# Set VSTS Compare Branch using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) using the documented REST API ([latest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/rest/api/vsts/)) you can initialize your first branch, create additional branches and update a GIT repository's default branch.

When updating the default branch, the new default branch automatically becomes the compare branch.

So my question is, is there a way using the REST API to modify the compare branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/Settings/Repository/{repository id}/Entries/me?api-version=4.1-preview.1`

Content-Type: `application/json`

Body:

```
{
    "Branches.Compare":"refs/heads/Dev1"
}
```

You can get repository id through [Git repositories](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories#get-a-list-of-repositories) REST API.

Comment: Thank you! worked perfectly.

Calling Get on the URI returns: Branches.Compare and Git/DefaultUserBranch

Also works on api version 4.1-Preview

was unable to find any supporting documentation though :(